# mvc form not submitting submit button name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm really frustrated about this as it was working before.

I have an mvc form with a submit button like this

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-hg btn-wide text-center" name="action" value="save" />
```

I then have a controller action receiving the form as this:

```
public ActionResult SaveEngagementActivity(EngagementActivity model, string action)
        {
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
```

The issue is that the browser is not sending the details of the submit button ie: the name and value

```
Id:cf6cedac-2078-495f-8d0b-a2415ed5439d
CreatedBy:c74038ec-77ea-475e-8d76-f3a6566f91a5
ActivityType:200005
Reference:
Supporter.Id:3734bded-4dad-4701-b668-03b54909b65d
Supporter.Label:C1000003,  Harris
Organisation.Id:21a0d1bc-58df-4e89-8c2e-414ce13e82ec
Organisation.Label:OR100102, Evenley St George's
DefaultContact:
ActivitySource:1
Owner.Id:c74038ec-77ea-475e-8d76-f3a6566f91a5
Owner.Label:Frank Lores-Penalver
EngagementActivityType:1
Alert:0
Approach.Id:22a24fcd-4d93-4d95-991e-6fe53c2a3842
Approach.Label:A010008, Indian Cookery Evening
StartDate:06/03/2015
DateCompleted:31/03/2015
FollowUpDate:31/03/2015
NumberOfAttendees:1
NumberOfOrganisations:1
NumbersOfHoursSpent:1
PledgeTypes:5
Summary:asdfsaf
Details:asdfas
```

It's really frustrating as this was working before...  Any help would be appreciated as this is taking unnecessary time.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EngagementActivity", "Activity", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct errors below", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 center-block text-center">
            <input 
                   type="submit" 
                   class="btn btn-primary btn-hg btn-wide text-center" 
                   name="action" 
                   value="save" />
                @*<i class="fui-check"></i>&nbsp;Save
            </input>*@
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 center-block text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-hg btn-wide text-center" name="action" value="saveandcopy" ><i class="fui-plus"></i>&nbsp;Save &amp; Copy
            </button> 
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I've included the whole form without the fields to save space. This was literally working fine yesterday today it doesn't...

Comment: Is it a normal submit (you haven't changed to using ajax?)

Comment: can you post the entire form html? or atleast form tag wrapping this input button.... and one more thing.. it will not send value to server if you are posting form using AJAX

Comment: I've ammended the post to include the form.

Comment: Stephen Muecke: is a normal form with some javascript validation, but the submission is not ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "EngagementActivity" action method on your controller ?

Because in your example you are calling  "Activity/EngagementActivity"

But on your controller code example I see (SaveEngagementActivity) :

```
public ActionResult SaveEngagementActivity(EngagementActivity model, string action)

@using (Html.BeginForm("EngagementActivity", "Activity", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
```

The correct should be :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEngagementActivity", "Activity", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
```